# How to disable user interaction on MKMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

How do you disable user interaction to an entire Map (MKMapView) in iOS? I just want to disable zooming, tapping, etc and show a static map. `[self.mapView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO]` didn't work. Found no working solutions via Google or other answers here on Stack *(pls link if you find a working answer..)*. Targeting iOS 5. There should be an easier way to do this.

Comment: FYI, I tried this and the app was rejected for not being interactive. I didn't use MKMapView, so I can't actually answer your question.

Comment: @SteveMallory Shouldn't be rejected for doing this in just one use case I think. Other apps do it. Have a look at foursquare: In one use case (Shop Detail View) the map is pretty much locked in place which makes sense since the content context is a single shop.

Comment: From my experience - it doesn't work when selected in interface builder by removing checkmark on "User Interaction Enabled" for the map view. However, setting it by code worked for me.

Comment: @SteveMallory I doubt that's the main reason the app was rejected, seeing as Apple has added built in params specifically to MKMapView to allow devs to toggle these abilities on or off. Perhaps they just meant a general lack of interactivity across your whole app.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The key is to disable zooms and scrolls.

In Objective-C:

```
self.mapView.zoomEnabled = false;
self.mapView.scrollEnabled = false;
self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled = false;
```

Or Swift:

```
mapView.isZoomEnabled = false
mapView.isScrollEnabled = false
mapView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

---

By the way, if you want a static map, you might consider using [`MKMapSnapshotter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapsnapshotter) instead. This creates an image representation of a map. If you have annotations or overlays, you have to render them manually, but, depending upon your use-case, map snapshots might do the job.

Comment: Ok this answer worked for me, for the most part. Taps are still getting through but that doesn't break my use-case and users cannot scroll or zoom so I'm happy. Thanks!

Comment: Using this, I was still able to use the two finger rotation and tilt gestures to displace the center focal point entirely out of view, though it was rather tedious.

Comment: What's the point of disabling user interaction if you have to still do it in code...?

Comment: Good tip! I simply set the userInteractionEnabled to false in my viewDidLoad, and that seemed to do the trick. The zoomEnabled and scrollEnabled changes may be redundant.

Answer (score 21):

You can do this in Interface Builder like this:

[image: Like this]

Answer (score 1):

How about this little hack! 
just place `UIView` on top of the `MKMapView` having all the same frame details. Also note that the `backgroundColor` of this view should be `clearColor`

Comment: will this make the [legal] button of the map view not clickable? will apple like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the enabled property of MKAnnotationView  to NO

For disabling Zoom, you can set `mapView.zoomEnabled = FALSE;`

**enabled**

A Boolean value indicating whether the annotation is enabled.

```
@property (nonatomic, getter=isEnabled) BOOL enabled
```

**Discussion**

The default value of this property is YES. If the value of this property is NO, the annotation view ignores touch events and cannot be selected. Subclasses may also display the annotation contents differently depending on the value of this property.

Comment: I don't understand how this applies to disable interaction to the entire map. I don't want the user to be able to interact anywhere within the entire Map -- in this particular use case.