# How to manually cancel MKMapView standard gesture recognizers

Tags: ios, mkmapview, uigesturerecognizer

I am working on my custom gesture on the map. It should work after 2s long press. All is fine, but after long press gesture I move fingers and map follows them... I need to escape this. I tried:

```
self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

But it seems not working...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable user interaction on MKMapView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418071/how-to-disable-user-interaction-on-mkmapview)

Comment: @Desdenova that answer does not work for me. Map gesture recognizers is working at moment I want to cancel them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working way. Collect all working on `UIMapView` gesture recognizers:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.myLongPressGestureRecognizer
        && otherGestureRecognizer != self.myPanGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if (self.otherGestureRecognizers == nil)
            self.otherGestureRecognizers = [NSMutableSet set];
        [self.otherGestureRecognizers addObject:otherGestureRecognizer];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And cancel them all when your gesture recognizer recognized:

```
- (IBAction)measureLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        for (UIGestureRecognizer *gr in self.otherGestureRecognizers)
        {
            gr.enabled = NO;
            gr.enabled = YES;
        }
        self.otherGestureRecognizers = nil;

        [self myLongPressDetectedAndMapFreezed];
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Collect recognizers while our custom `self.measureGestureRecognizer` trying to recognize gesture:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer == self.measureGestureRecognizer)
    {
        if (self.otherGestureRecognizers == nil)
            self.otherGestureRecognizers = [NSMutableSet set];
        [self.otherGestureRecognizers addObject:otherGestureRecognizer];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And when I need to cancel all Gesture Recognizers:

```
self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gr in self.otherGestureRecognizers) {
    if (gr.enabled) {
        gr.enabled = NO;
        gr.enabled = YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (Swift 4)

```
guard   let splitPanGesture = splitVc.view.gestureRecognizers?.first(where: { ($0 as? UIPanGestureRecognizer) != nil }),
        let mapPanGesture = mapView.subviews.first?.gestureRecognizers?.first(where: { ($0 as? UIPanGestureRecognizer) != nil }) else { return }

splitPanGesture.require(toFail: mapPanGesture)
```